# Problem with deploying react app through Github page

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have created a portfolio using react. I now want to deploy it through Github pages. I followed all the instructions from the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) but it is not working.
I followed the following steps:

1. npm install --save gh-pages
2. "scripts": {
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
3. npm run deploy

My deployed portfolio now looks like this: https://nahidaislam.github.io/portfolio/

Can anyone say what the problem is? Here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/nahidaislam/portfolio

Comment: You have to create a [nahidaislam.github.io](https://pages.github.com/) project that contains the build of your portfolio project. But since it's a satically hosted by github so you have to use a hash router.

Comment: Do you mean I have to create github repo named  nahidaislam.github.io and push my build folder in that repo? 
I had a build folder but it was in gitignore.

Comment: Yes, push the build in that project and use hash router instead.

Comment: Thank you. The hash router works better than the browser router.